# JsonMappingException: Cannot find a deserialzer for non-concrete Map type

Tags: java, json

I am new to java!
I am trying to read objects of type Admin, containing 3 strings, from a JSON file and store them in a List. I am getting "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type" but it seems I cannot find a solution.
What is a solution for my code so that I can load the list from the file?

Code snippet :

```
    private static List<Admin> admins=new ArrayList<Admin>();

    public static void loadAdminsFromFile() { /*LOAD THE LIST WITH JSON(ADMIN) OBJECTS*/
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("*path to file*"));
            TypeReference<List<Admin>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<Admin>>() {};
            admins = mapper.readValue(inputStream, typeReference);
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Admin class :

```
package model;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Admin {

    private String username;
    private String ID;
    private String password;

    public Admin() {}

    public Admin(String username, String ID, String password) {
        this.username=username;
        this.ID=ID;
        this.password=password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(TextField username) {
        this.username = username.getText();
    }

    public String getID() {
        return this.ID;
    }

    public void setID(TextField ID) {
        this.ID = ID.getText();
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(TextField password) {
        this.password = password.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(this==o) return true;
        if(o==null || getClass()!=o.getClass()) return false;

        Admin admin=(Admin) o;

        if(!username.equals(admin.username)) return false;
        if(!ID.equals(admin.ID)) return false;
        if(!password.equals(admin.password)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode (){
        int result=username.hashCode();
        result=31*result+ID.hashCode();
        result=31*result+password.hashCode();

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Admin -> " + username + ID + password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add sample file?

Comment: can you also post the `Admin` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override the setters method to accept String values:

```
....
public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
....
```